# how to use the popToViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to navigate to another ViewController but it's not connected by segue, so I programmed the nav bar and what I want it's when y push the button named "Start Over" the ViewController that I'm requesting appears, but this errors appears:

"Cannot convert value of type MemeEditorViewController.Type yo expected argument type UIViewController"

So I don't how to deal with. Here's my code, maybe you could help me better.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"Start Over", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "startOver")
    }
    func startOver(){
        if let navigationController = self.navigationController {
            navigationController.popToViewController(MemeEditorViewController, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: PopViewController is not push a view controller its function like if You press A button then From VC1 you navigate to VC2 and on VC2 there is Button called B . Now when u press B and u use PopToViewController then it will navigate to VC1.. so its not push its pop(BackToPrevious) ViwController. (here VC -> ViewController)

Comment: What u want exactly need to push from A-B or Want pop from B-A ?

Answer (score 11):

if there only one `viewcontroller` with type `MemeEditorViewController` you can find the controller and pop to it in this way :

```
let  vc =  self.navigationController?.viewControllers.filter({$0 is MemeEditorViewController}).first

self.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc!, animated: true)
```

or you should need know the place of vc in the stack then find it :

```
let  vc =  self.navigationController?.viewControllers[1]
```

Note: when you push a `viewcontroller` the `navgationcontroller` will store it in the array `viewcontrollers` with a strong reference. you can find the `viewcontroller` instance you have pushed in it .

hope it be helpful :D

Comment: Bravo...you saved my day you sir :-) +1 this should be marked as answer